# Mysql multiple joins on self and other table performance

Tags: mysql, performance, self-join

I have two tables:

categories
 - id
 - parent_id

categories_products
 - product_id
 - category_id

Categories has about 80 entries, categories_products about 20'000.
I'm joining categories with itself and categories_products with this query:

```
SELECT c0.id AS cat_id
FROM categories AS c0
LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON c0.id = c1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories_products ON  
  c0.id = categories_products.category_id
  OR c1.id = categories_products.category_id
  OR c2.id = categories_products.category_id
GROUP BY c0.id;
```

The explanation:

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys                      | key                                | key_len | ref              | rows  | Extra                                                        |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c0                  | index | NULL                               | fk_categories_parent_id            | 5       | NULL             |    86 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c1                  | ref   | fk_categories_parent_id            | fk_categories_parent_id            | 5       | preview_m2.c0.id |     3 | Using index                                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c2                  | ref   | fk_categories_parent_id            | fk_categories_parent_id            | 5       | preview_m2.c1.id |     3 | Using where; Using index                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | categories_products | index | fk_categories_products_category_id | fk_categories_products_category_id | 4       | NULL             | 25273 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+---------------------+-------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The query takes about 1.5 seconds, can anyone tell me how i can improve this?

Comment: well since you're only pulling out c0.id, and you're left joining, you may as well just `select id from categories`

Comment: The query is a bit more complex than that but i reduced to a minimum. In fact i'm also selecting stuff from categories_products.

Comment: out of curiosity, how long does it take, and what does the explain plan look like when you dont use the `or`s? they can be bugbears for optimisation

Comment: With **and** instead of **or** it's blazing fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @ABC's suggestion:

- Get rid of unneeded joins
- Get rid of `LEFT`
- Use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`
- Add parens just in case you tack something on the end (and it would belong to the last SELECT when it should belong to the UNION.

  ```
    ( SELECT  c0.id AS cat_id
          FROM  categories AS c0
          JOIN  categories_products ON c0.id = categories_products.category_id 
    )
  union  DISTINCT 
    ( SELECT  c0.id AS cat_id
          FROM  categories AS c0
          JOIN  categories AS c1 ON c0.id = c1.parent_id
          JOIN  categories_products ON c1.id = categories_products.category_id 
    )
  union  DISTINCT 
    ( SELECT  c0.id AS cat_id
          FROM  categories AS c0
          JOIN  categories AS c1 ON c0.id = c1.parent_id
          JOIN  categories AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
          JOIN  categories_products ON c2.id = categories_products.category_id 
    );
  ```

Why even mention `categories_products`?  It seems to bring nothing to the table.  I would expect this to give you the same resultset:

```
SELECT id AS cat_id FROM  categories;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to union all instead of OR.With use of union all it might do an index scan which will help run query faster

Query can be

> 

```
SELECT c0.id AS cat_id
FROM categories AS c0
LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON c0.id = c1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories_products ON  
  c0.id = categories_products.category_id
  union all 
  SELECT c0.id AS cat_id
FROM categories AS c0
LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON c0.id = c1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories_products ON  
c1.id = categories_products.category_id
  union all 
 SELECT c0.id AS cat_id
FROM categories AS c0
LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON c0.id = c1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN categories_products ON c2.id = categories_products.category_id
```

I have not included group by..based on result required group by can be used on entire outer loop..This might help only in case where index on  categories_products.category_id exists.Number of rows in explain plan would be more but if index is used then query would run faster :)

Comment: Ok, that's about 2x faster